# Model testing with MiniTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am using the MiniTest framework, and want to write a model test. This is my test code:

```
it "must find or create authentication" do
  auth = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid( @auth.provider,
  @auth.uid )
  val = auth.nil?
  if val==true
    Authentication.create_with_omniauth @auth
  end
end
```

This test checks to see if the `Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid` method exists, and if `auth` is nil, it will create a new `auth`.

I wrote it using an `if` clause, but I don't know if it is true or not. How can I correct this test?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no code in your question, I am going to assume you are using [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) and have it configured properly, because that is what I am most familiar with.

Let's assume you have the following code:

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_provider_and_uid provider, uid
    self.where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first_or_initalize
  end
end
```

And further, I will assume you have the following fixture data in `test/fixtures/authentications.yml`

```
test_auth:
  provider: twitter
  uid: abc123
  user: test_user
```

I would have a test similar to the following:

```
describe Authentication do

  describe "find_by_provider_and_uid" do

    it "retrieves existing authentication records" do
      existing_auth = authentications :test_auth
      found_auth = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid existing_auth.provider, existing_auth.uid
      refute_nil found_auth, "It should return an object"
      assert found_auth.persisted?, "The record should have existed previously"
      assert_equal existing_auth, found_auth
    end

    it "creates a new authentication of one doesn't exist" do
      new_auth = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid "twitter", "IDONTEXIST"
      refute_nil new_auth, "It should return an object"
      assert new_auth.new_record?, "The record should not have existed previously"
    end

  end

end
```

FWIW, I don't like the name of this method. The name is similar to the dynamic finders, but the behavior is different. I would rename the method to `for_provider_and_uid`.